# Keycloak H2 login failure: constraint already exists

Tags: constraints, h2, keycloak

we are using keycloak with an h2 database. This went pretty well until yesterday, when keycloak could not connect to the h2 database anymore all for sudden throwing:

```
Constraint "FK_OUSE064PLMLR732LXJCN1Q5F1" already exists; SQL 
statement: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.SCOPE_MAPPING ADD CONSTRAINT 
PUBLIC.FK_OUSE064PLMLR732LXJCN1Q5F1 FOREIGN KEY(CLIENT_ID) INDEX 
PUBLIC.FK_OUSE064PLMLR732LXJCN1Q5F1_INDEX_8 REFERENCES 
PUBLIC.CLIENT(ID) NOCHECK [90045-196]
```

I replicated the *.mv.db file and tried to connect locally using razorsql, running in the same issue. Since i cannot connect to the db i cannot fix it either.
This seems to be a deadlock somehow. Any ideas how to fix it or what to test?

Comment: It looks like your database file was operated by different versions of H2 (possibly 1.4.196 and 1.4.197) that is not supported in any way. You can write a dummy implementation of `org.h2.api.DatabaseEventListener` and try to open a JDBC connection with `;DATABASE_EVENT_LISTENER='packageName.ClassName'` appended to JDBC URL. If connection will be initialized successfully, you need to export your database into SQL script (`RUNSCRIPT TO 'output.sql'`) and create a new database with that script. You can also try to use the Recover tool.

Comment: that did the trick, thanks!