# Keycloak doesn't start after upgrade(8 -->12) and first restart

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to upgrade keycloak(running in standalone mode) from version 8 to 12. I have followed the steps mentioned [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/)

I deleted the data/tx-object-store/ transaction directory, and copied the standalone directory from version 8.
I ran the upgrade script. I can see that there are no failures and all the steps were SUCCESS.

I try to start the server with this command

```
sudo ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 &
```

Server started successfully, I can reach keycloak admin console and also able to login. I can see that the data(users, groups, etc) is successfully migrated as well.

After this, I stopped keycloak

```
sudo ./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

Which ran Okay. Now If I try to start it again, I see the following errors and keycloak doesn't boot up

```
 06:30:00,080 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
        at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:377)
        at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lazyInit(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:65)
        at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$waitForLock$2(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:96)
        at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:654)
        at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.waitForLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:94)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:136)
        at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:228)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:129)
        at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:29)
        at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:115)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2815)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:371)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:283)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:93)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:140)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:159)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
        at org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:371)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:690)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1322)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:632)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:604)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Constraint "FK_OUSE064PLMLR732LXJCN1Q5F1" already exists; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.SCOPE_MAPPING ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.FK_OUSE064PLMLR732LXJCN1Q5F1 FOREIGN KEY(CLIENT_ID) INDEX PUBLIC.FK_OUSE064PLMLR732LXJCN1Q5F1_INDEX_8 REFERENCES PUBLIC.CLIENT(ID) NOCHECK [90045-197]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.tryUpdate(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:110)
        at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.update(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:78)
        at org.h2.engine.MetaRecord.execute(MetaRecord.java:58)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:775)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:286)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:280)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:66)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:179)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:157)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:140)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:351)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:124)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:103)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
        ... 57 more
```

I am using H2 in memory database. I tried installing keycloak 12 and upgrading several times. Everytime I have the same issue, Starts successfully the first time, and then fails there after.

Can anyone please help?  It looks like when I start the server the second time, it is trying to do migration again.. Not sure though.

Comment: Update from 4.7 to 12 also not working too, we made an intermediate step to version 11 this seems to work.

Comment: @ThomasBrüggemann  thanks for the feedback. I tried upgrading to 11 from 8. I still get the same error.

Comment: I forgot that we need to make a workaround for this H2 Bug: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1247
(Backup&Restore Database)
But don't know what version of H2 comes with Version 8 of Keycloak.

Comment: I managed to get it working by doing a step by step upgrade. 8-->9 9-->10 10-->11 11-->12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Get a copy of H2 1.4.196 (bug as noted here and at [Keycloak H2 login failure: constraint already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151678/keycloak-h2-login-failure-constraint-already-exists) is with 4.1.197)

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.196/h2-1.4.196.jar

2.Get a copy of H2 1.4.197or later

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.199/h2-1.4.199.jar

3. Take a copy of DB backup from before the upgrade (ours was from 4.6.0)
   Create a dump (will create backup.sql) with:

```
java -cp ~/ba-docker/h2-1.4.196.jar org.h2.tools.Script -url "jdbc:h2:./kc-data/keycloak;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" -user sa -password sa (user and password can be confirmed in your standalone file)
```

4. Restore DB with newer version of H2
   Command by default uses backup.sql

```
    java -cp ~/ba-docker/h2-1.4.199.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url "jdbc:h2:./kcdata-restore;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" -user sa -password sa
```

5. In KC data directory

- Delete keycloak.mv.db and keycloak.trace.db

```
     rm keycloak.trace.db
     rm keycloak.mv.db
```

- Copy your kcdata-restore.mv.db from step 4 to keycloak.mv.db

```
        cp ../../kcdata-restore.mv.db keycloak.mv.db
```

6. Follow standard KC upgrade

- Delete tx-object-store

```
    rm -Rf tx-object-store/
```

And you should now be able to start, stop and restart without issues.

Comment: I opened an issue: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-18084 but apparently even documenting this is overboard for RedHat, WOW!!

Comment: At step 3, I ran into `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: backup.sql (Permission denied)"` until I figured out that I can define the backup sql file path with `-script` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Copied answer from : https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-10-0-2-doesnt-start-locally-twice/3320
Courtesy : @lieven_wk

Came across the same problem when trying to upgrade 3.1.0.Final to 11.0.2. Found out this was caused by https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1247 26.

As a workaround, I dumped & restored the keycloak H2 datasource file before starting the new version:

Given:

- Old KeyCloak is installed in keycloak-3.1.0.Final
- New KeyCloak is    installed in keycloak-11.0.2
- Running standalone setup
- Datasource is configured with below connection URL
   jdbc:h2:${jboss.server.data.dir}/keycloak;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE

Dump old sql:

```
java -cp keycloak-3.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/h2database/h2/main/h2-1.3.173.jar org.h2.tools.Script -url jdbc:h2:keycloak-3.1.0.Final/standalone/data/keycloak -user sa -password MYPASS -script ~/keycloak-testbackup.sql
```

Restore to new H2 file (make sure file doesn’t exists prior to running the restore):

```
java -cp keycloak-11.0.2/modules/system/layers/base/com/h2database/h2/main/h2-1.4.197.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:keycloak-11.0.2/standalone/data/keycloak -user sa -password MYPASS -script ~/keycloak-testbackup.sql
```

Now upon starting the application server (keycloak-11.0.2) for the first time, the schema is migrated to the latest version, and remains running properly at each restart.

Comment: This worked for me on the same issue while migrating from 9.0.2 => 15.0.2